# callBack is not a Function error log in and sign up system

Tags: javascript, html, callback

I am working on making a multi player game but I am having some problems with my log in and sign up system. Every time I try to log in the server stops running and I get the error callBack is not a function.

Here is my app.js code:

```
    var mongojs = require("mongojs");
    //Connect to database
    var db = mongojs('localhost:27017/myGame', ['users','progress']);
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var serv = require('http').Server(app);

    app.get('/',function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
    });
    app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

    serv.listen(8080);
    console.log("Server started.");

    var SOCKET_LIST = {};

    var Entity = function(){
        var self = {
            x:250,
            y:250,
            spdX:0,
            spdY:0,
            id:""
        };
        self.update = function(){
            self.updatePosition();
        };
        self.updatePosition = function(){
            self.x += self.spdX;
            self.y += self.spdY;
        };
        self.getDistance = function(pt){
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.x-pt.x,2) + Math.pow(self.y-pt.y,2));
        };
        return self;
    };

    var Player = function(id){
        var self = Entity();
        self.id = id;
        self.number = "" + Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
        self.pressingRight = false;
        self.pressingLeft = false;
        self.pressingUp = false;
        self.pressingDown = false;
        self.pressingShoot = false;
        self.mouseAngle = 0;
        self.maxSpd = 10;

        var super_update = self.update;
        self.update = function(){
            self.updateSpd();
            super_update();

            if(self.pressingShoot){
                self.shootBullet(self.mouseAngle);
            }
        };

        self.shootBullet = function(angle){
           var b = Bullet(self.id, angle);
           b.x = self.x;
           b.y = self.y;
        };

        self.updateSpd = function(){
            if(self.pressingRight)
                self.spdX = self.maxSpd;
            else if(self.pressingLeft)
                self.spdX = -self.maxSpd;
            else
                self.spdX = 0;

            if(self.pressingUp)
                self.spdY = -self.maxSpd;
            else if(self.pressingDown)
                self.spdY = self.maxSpd;
            else
                self.spdY = 0;
        };
        Player.list[id] = self;

        initPack.player.push({
            id:self.id,
            x:self.x,
            y:self.y,
            number:self.number,
        });
        return self;
    };
    Player.list = {};
    Player.onConnect = function(socket){
        var player = Player(socket.id);
        socket.on('keyPress',function(data){
            if(data.inputId === 'left')
                player.pressingLeft = data.state;
            else if(data.inputId === 'right')
                player.pressingRight = data.state;
            else if(data.inputId === 'up')
                player.pressingUp = data.state;
            else if(data.inputId === 'down')
                player.pressingDown = data.state;
            else if(data.inputId === 'shoot')
                player.pressingShoot = data.state;
            else if(data.inputId === 'mouseAngle')
                player.mouseAngle = data.state;
        });
    };
    Player.onDisconnect = function(socket){
        delete Player.list[socket.id];
        removePack.player.push(socket.id);
    };
    Player.update = function(){
        var pack = [];
        for(var i in Player.list){
            var player = Player.list[i];
            player.update();
            pack.push({
                id:player.id,
                x:player.x,
                y:player.y,
            });
        }
        return pack;
    };

    var Bullet = function(parent, angle){
        var self = Entity();
        self.id = Math.random();
        self.spdX = Math.cos(angle/180*Math.PI) * 10;
        self.spdY = Math.sin(angle/180*Math.PI) * 10;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.timer = 0;
        self.toRemove = false;
        var super_update = self.update;
        self.update = function(){
            if(self.timer++ > 100)
                self.toRemove = true;
            super_update();

            for(var i in Player.list){
                var p = Player.list[i];
                if(self.getDistance(p) < 32 && self.parent !== p.id){
                    //handle collision ex: hp--;
                    self.toRemove = true;
                }
            }
        };
        Bullet.list[self.id] = self;
        initPack.bullet.push({
            id: self.id,
            x: self.x,
            y: self.y,
        });
            return self;
    };
    Bullet.list = {};

    Bullet.update = function(){
        var pack = [];
        for(var i in Bullet.list) {
            var bullet = Bullet.list[i];
            bullet.update();
            if (bullet.toRemove){
                delete Bullet.list[i];
            removePack.bullet.push(bullet.id);
        }else
            pack.push({
                id:bullet.id,
                x:bullet.x,
                y:bullet.y
            });
        }
        return pack;
    };

    var isValidPassword = function(data,callBack){
        db.users.find({username:data.username,password:data.password}, function(err,res){
            if(res.length > 0)
                callBack(true);
            else
                callBack(false);
        })
    };



    //Test to see if username already exists]
    var isUsernameTaken = function(data,callBack){
        db.users.find({username:data.username}, function(err,res){
            if(res.length > 0)
    callBack(true);
            else
                callBack(false);
        })
    };

    //Add user
    var addUser = function(data,callBack){
        db.users.insert({username:data.username,password:data.password}, function(err){
            callBack();
        })
    };

    var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.id = Math.random();
        SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

        socket.on('logIn', function(data){
           if(isValidPassword(data)){
               Player.onConnect(socket);
               socket.emit('signInResponse', {success:true});
           } else {
               socket.emit('signInResponse', {success: false});
           }
        });

        //Listen for sign up package
        socket.on('signUp', function(data){
           if(isUsernameTaken(data)){
               socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:false});
           } else {
               addUser(data);
               socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:true});
           }
        });

        socket.on('disconnect',function(){
            delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
            Player.onDisconnect(socket);
        });

        socket.on('sendMsgToServer', function(data){
        var playerName = ("" + socket.id).slice(2,7);
        for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
            SOCKET_LIST[i].emit('addToChat', playerName + ": " + data);
        }
        });

    });

    var initPack = {player:[],bullet:[]};
    var removePack = {player:[],bullet:[]};


    setInterval(function(){
        var pack = {
            player:Player.update(),
            bullet:Bullet.update(),
        }

        for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
            var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
            socket.emit('init',initPack);
            socket.emit('update',pack);
            socket.emit('remove',removePack);
        }
        initPack.player = [];
        initPack.bullet = [];``
        removePack.player = [];
        removePack.bullet = [];

    },1000/25);

and here is my index.html:

<div id="signDiv">
    Username: <input id="signDiv-username" type="text"></input><br>
    Password: <input id="signDiv-password" type="password"></input>
    <button id="signDiv-logIn">Log in</button>
    <button id="signDiv-signUp">Sign up</button>
</div>

<div id="gameDiv" style="display:none;">
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<!--Game Chat-->
<div id="chat-text" style="width:500px;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <div>Hello!</div>
</div>

<form id="chat-form">
<input id="chat-input" type="text" style="width:500px"></input>
</form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>

    var socket = io();

    //log in and sign up for game
    var signDiv = document.getElementById('signDiv');
    var signDivUsername = document.getElementById('signDiv-username');
    var signDivLogIn = document.getElementById('signDiv-logIn');
    var signDivSignUp = document.getElementById('signDiv-signUp');
    var signDivPassword = document.getElementById('signDiv-password');

    signDivLogIn.onclick = function(){
      socket.emit('logIn', {username:signDivUsername.value, password:signDivPassword.value});
    };

    signDivSignUp.onclick = function(){
    socket.emit('signUp', {username:signDivUsername.value, password:signDivPassword.value});
    };

    socket.on('signInResponse', function(data){
       if(data.success){
           signDiv.style.display = 'none';
           gameDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
       } else
           alert("Log in unsuccessful")
    });

    socket.on('signUpResponse', function(data){
        if(data.success){
            alert("Sing up successful")
        } else
            alert("Sign up unsuccessful")
    });

    //Game chat, get elements
    var chatText = document.getElementById('chat-text');
    var chatInput = document.getElementById('chat-input');
    var chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-form');

    //Socket on for chat
    socket.on('addToChat', function(data){
        chatText.innerHTML += '<div>' + data + '</div>';
    });

    //Submit chat
    chatForm.onsubmit = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      socket.emit('sendMsgToServer', chatInput.value);
      chatInput.value = '';
    };

    //Game
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';

    var Player = function(initPack){
        var self = {};
        self.id = initPack.id;
        self.number = initPack.number;
        self.x = initPack.x;
        self.y = initPack.y;
        Player.list[self.id] = self;
        return self;
    };
    Player.list= {};

    var Bullet = function(initPack){
        var self = {};
        self.id = initPack.id;
        self.x = initPack.x;
        self.y = initPack.y;
        Bullet.list[self.id] = self;
        return self;
    };
Bullet.list = {};

    //Initialisation package
socket.on('init', function(data){
   for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
       new Player(data.player[i]);
   }
   for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i ++){
       new Bullet(data.bullet[i])
   }
});

    //Update package
socket.on('update', function(data){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
        var pack = data.player[i];
        var p = Player.list[pack.id];
        if(p){
            if(pack.x !== undefined)
                p.x = pack.x;
            if(pack.y !== undefined)
                p.y = pack.y;
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++){
        var pack = data.bullet[i];
        var b = Bullet.list[data.bullet[i].id];
        if(b){
            if(pack.x !== undefined)
                b.x = pack.x;
            if(pack.y !== undefined)
                b.y = pack.y;
        }
    }
});

    //Remove package
    socket.on('remove',function(data){
        for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
            delete Player.list[data.player[i]];
        }
        for(var i = 0 ; i < data.bullet.length; i++){
            delete Bullet.list[data.bullet[i]];
        }
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        for(var i in Player.list)
            ctx.fillText(Player.list[i].number,Player.list[i].x,Player.list[i].y);
        for(var i in Bullet.list)
            ctx.fillRect(Bullet.list[i].x-5,Bullet.list[i].y-5,10,10);
    },40);

    document.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 68)    //d
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:true});

    };
    document.onkeyup = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 68)    //d
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'right',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'down',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'left',state:false});
        else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
            socket.emit('keyPress',{inputId:'up',state:false});
    };

    document.onmousedown = function(event){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'shoot', state:true});
    };
    document.onmouseup = function (event){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'shoot', state:false});
    };
    document.onmousemove = function(event){
      var x = -250 + event.clientX - 8;
      var y = -250 + event.clientY -8;
      var angle = Math.atan2(y,x)/Math.PI*180;
      socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'mouseAngle', state:angle});
    };

</script>
```

I have tried a few different things and sometimes gotten the sign up working but never the log in. I am using a mongoDB database which all seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems like you are not passing any callback's function to isValidPassword,isUsernameTaken etc.

see this bit,

```
var isUsernameTaken = function(data,callBack){
  db.users.find({username:data.username}, function(err,res){
    if(res.length > 0)
      callBack(true);
    else
      callBack(false);
  })
};

    //Listen for sign up package
  socket.on('signUp', function(data){
    if(isUsernameTaken(data)){
      socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:false});
    } else {
      addUser(data);
      socket.emit('signUpResponse',{success:true});
    }
  });
```

the above can be written as,

```
//Listen for sign up package
  socket.on('signUp', function (data) {
    var callback = function (isTaken) {
      if (isTaken) {
        socket.emit('signUpResponse', {success: false});
      } else {
        addUser(data);
        socket.emit('signUpResponse', {success: true});
      }

    };
    isUsernameTaken(data , callback)

  });
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I changed this and also the log in package but I still keep getting the error CallBack is not a function for the Add User, any ideas?